# "cat urls.txt | gsutil -m cp -I gs://target-bucket-name/" consistently hangs after transferring ~10,000 files

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to copy ~80,000 images from one google cloud storage bucket to another.
I am initiating this operation from a mac with google cloud sdk 180.0.1 which contains gsutil 4.28.

The ~url of each image to be transferred in in a text file which I feed to gsutil cp like so ...

```
$cat urls.txt | gsutil -m cp -I gs://target-bucket-name/
```

wherein urls.txt looks like ...

```
head -3 urls.txt 
gs://source-bucket-name/1506567870546.jpg
gs://source-bucket-name/1506567930548.jpg
gs://source-bucket-name/1507853339446.jpg
```

The process consistently hangs after ~10,000 of the images have been transferred.

I have edited $HOME/.boto to uncomment:

```
parallel_composite_upload_threshold = 0
```

This has not prevented the operation from hanging.

I am uncertain what causes the hanging.

The underlying need is for a general utility to copy N items from one bucket to another. I need a work around that will enable me to accomplish that mission.

**UPDATE**

Removing the -m option seems to work around the hanging problem but the file transfer is now significantly slower. I would like to be able avoid the hanging problem whilst still gaining the speed that comes with using concurrency if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. gstuil should not be hanging. This is a bug. Could you record the output of gsutl -D and when it hangs, create an issue in the [gsutil github repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues) with the output attached and comment here with a link to it? You can use the following command to log the output:

   ```
   $ cat urls.txt | gsutil -D -m cp -I gs://target-bucket-name/ 2>&1 | tee output
   ```
2. In the meanwhile, you could try experimenting with reducing the number of threads and processes that the parallel mode (-m) uses by changing these defaults in your boto file.

   ```
   parallel_process_count = 1    # Default - 12
   parallel_thread_count = 10    # Default - 10
   ```
3. Note that gsutil has options to copy all files in a bucket or subdirectory to a new bucket, as well as only copy files that have changed or do not exist in the target with the following commands:

   ```
   gsutil -m cp gs://source-bucket/ gs://target-bucket
   gsutil -m cp 'gs://source-bucket/dir/**' gs://target-bucket
   gsutil -m rsync -r gs://source-bucket gs://target-bucket
   ```

Comment: Thanks. As of gcloud 182 (gsutil 4.28) on macos, it appears to be working.